# Code block inside withContext(Dispatchers.Main) not running

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to **coroutines**. I am using the below code to fetch a list of music in the user's device and displaying it. But the code inside the `withContext` block doesn't seem to run. The app just exits as soon as it is run. And there are no issues printed in the **logcat**.

```swift
    private suspend fun fetchMusic() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val mediaList = getAllAudioFromDevice(this@MainActivity)
            setListOnMainThread(mediaList)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun setListOnMainThread(mediaList: List<MusicModel>){
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            setData(mediaList)
        }
    }
```

What can be the issue here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`launch` creates a new coroutine and fires it off without waiting for it to finish.

Typically, a clean implementation of coroutines would be to have each suspend function handle switching to the appropriate dispatcher. If it's an action that you are only ever going to do in the background, the function should start with `= withContext`. For instance, in your case, if `getAllAudioFromDevice` is something you always want to do in the background, it should look like:

```
private suspend fun getAllAudioFromDevice() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // fetch it
    // return it
}
```

and then your `fetchMusic` would be much simpler:

```
private suspend fun fetchMusic() {
    val mediaList = getAllAudioFromDevice(this@MainActivity)
    setListOnMainThread(mediaList)
}
```

or maybe `getAllAudioFromDevice ()` is a function you want to be able to call in the foreground or background, and not necessarily from a coroutine. Then you would leave it as is (not a suspend function), and wrap calls in `withContext()` as needed like this:

```
private suspend fun fetchMusic() {
    val mediaList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        getAllAudioFromDevice(this@MainActivity)
    }
    setListOnMainThread(mediaList)
}
```

You also mention the app exits as soon as it runs. Why does it exit? Is there an uncaught exception with a stack trace we can look at?